# Why am I being told I need administrative privileges while on an administrator account?

Tags: windows-8, administrator

I'm on an administrator account on Windows 8. I have UAC disabled. Still, when I go to install certain programs, it fails and rolls back because it needs administrative privileges. Why?

Comment: UAC is enabled. Check out the wording on the slider bar: "Do not notify". This does not say "Disable UAC".

Answer (score 2):

You're part of the administrators group but you're not running elevated.

Comment: I've seen this too - some actions that require administrator privileges proceed without issue and others fail because of this same issue.  If UAC is off shouldn't elevation happen transparently?

Comment: @Matt: That would be broken behavior. Turning off UAC is like a gun without a safety, not like a gun that shoots every time someone gets in your way.

Comment: A good and answer and a stylish analogy.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Why do some actions that require admin privs proceed without prompt while others do, and yet still others just fail - all of this while I am logged on as admin?

Comment: @Matt: If I knew some of the specific actions you're talking about, I could give you a more detailed answer. But the basic idea is that having administrative powers would be a bad thing if they were invoked even when you didn't want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the UAC slider to the bottom, the **UAC is still active**!

This is a change to Win8. This is done because the *Windows Store Apps* require an active UAC.

If you don't use the apps, use regedit to change the value `EnableLUA` from **1** to **0**.

Comment: Or just be aware of the behaviour of UAC. It's not that hard to work with.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  yes, I always run with UAC and the highest level. If he wants to ruin his Windows he can do it.

Comment: That registry key is located where?

Comment: is the search in regedit.exe broken? Here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System